# problem with 'ABSOLUTE_MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH' - Magento 1.9.4.3

Tags: magento-1.9, database

After upgrading `Magento to 1.9.4`, I have this issue when logging in the website (as a customer).

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'ABSOLUTE_MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH'
>   in
>   /home/..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Passwordlength.php
>   on line 44

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `App.php` class under the following path:

`app/code/local/Mage/Core`

Make sure to remove the file from local or add the following constant after this line `const ADMIN_STORE_ID = 0;`

```
/**
 * The absolute minimum of password length for all types of passwords
 *
 * With changing this value also need to change:
 * 1. in `js/prototype/validation.js` declarations `var minLength = 7;` in two places;
 * 2. in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/system.xml`
 *    comments for fields `min_password_length` and `min_admin_password_length`
 *    `<comment>Please enter a number 7 or greater in this field.</comment>`;
 * 3. in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml` value `<min_password_length>7</min_password_length>`
 *    and, maybe, value `<min_admin_password_length>14</min_admin_password_length>`
 *    (if the absolute minimum of password length is higher then this value);
 * 4. maybe, the value of deprecated `const MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH` in `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php`,
 *    (if the absolute minimum of password length is higher then this value).
 */

const ABSOLUTE_MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 7;
```